# VC: How to specify 'undecorate' in .def file?

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++

For some reason, I have to create .def file for a .lib file. I successfully do it for some cardinal functions, but I don't know how to handle 'undecorate' functions. For example, GetHostNameW() in ws2_32.lib. Dumpbin shows the entry for GetHostNameW() should be:

```
DLL name     : WS2_32.dll
Symbol name  : _GetHostNameW@8
Type         : code
Name type    : undecorate
Hint         : 8
Name         : GetHostNameW
```

In my .def, I tried lines:

```
GetHostNameW@8 GetHostNameW
GetHostNameW
_GetHostNameW@8
```

But none of them produce exact the same entry as original ws2_32.lib. The main difference is 'name type' and 'hint'. Can anybody tell me how to do it? Thanks.